# Vue 3 define Async Component with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am new to vue 3 and I find that there are `defineAsyncComponent`. I want to know if I can do something like below

```
const RemoteApp = defineAsyncComponent({
  loader: async () => {
      const response = axios.get('') 
      // the response body { "html": "<p>{{ message }}</p>", json: { "message": "hello world" } }
      const { html, json } = response.data
      return defineComponent({
        template: html,
        data() {
          return json
        }
      })
  }
});
const app = createApp(RemoteApp);

app.mount("#app");
```

However, it cannot render and only have

```
<html lang=""><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>vue 3</title>
  <script defer="" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script defer="" src="/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but vue-tailwind doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app" data-v-app=""><!----></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  

</body></html>
```

it only have `<!---->`
Do any bbody can help what I am wrong?

Comment: Since parent component is supposed to handle the loading of async component, RemoteApp cannot be root component